# Основная информация о песочницах

Tags: песочница, sandbox

Предлагаю в этом топике разобрать, какие есть песочницы и что они умеют.

Мой интерес к ним чисто в том, что хотелось бы иметь возможность останавливать и сохранять память приложений и запускать, когда понадобится (аналог гибернации windows).

Но т.к. песочницы много чего умеют, то хотелось бы собрать основную информацию в одном месте, чтобы потом было просто ее найти.

Comment: Есть класс программ которые я не уверен подходят ли в эту категорию хочу посоветоваться перед добавлением. Программы Shadow User и Shadow Defender.

Comment: Виртуальные машины вроде VirtualBox к песочницам относятся?

Comment: Я бы все же к виртуальным машинам отнес. Одно дело эмулировать целый ПК. Другое доступ к ресурсам ОС.

Answer (score 1):

### Sandboxie

[Официальный сайт](http://www.sandboxie.com/)

Плюсы

- Поддержка 32 и 64х разрядных приложений
- Есть корпоративная версия (консоль для управления)

Минусы

- Платная (Shareware лицензия)
- Только под Microsoft Windows

### Deep Freeze

[Официальный сайт](http://www.faronics.com/en/Products/DeepFreeze/DeepFreezeCorporate.aspx)

### BufferZone

[Официальный сайт](http://www.trustware.com/)

### Returnil

[Официальный сайт](http://www.returnilvirtualsystem.com/)